# Conflict in Alert.Dialog

Tags: android, listview, dialog

I have a listview in my activity, and when I click on a button a dialog is opened in this way:

```
private void openDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(FriendActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Add friend");
    builder.setMessage("Add the name and the phone number for your friend.");
    LayoutInflater fi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = fi.inflate(R.layout.friend_dialog, null);
    final EditText name = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edit1);
    final EditText number = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edit2);

    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String namee = name.getText().toString().trim();
            String numberr = number.getText().toString().trim();
            db.insertFriend(namee, numberr);
            //updateAdapter();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // do nothing
        }
    });
    builder.setView(v);
    builder.show();
}
```

Okay, that works!
Problem is when I click on the EditText they keyboard pops up, but when I press back to disable it or even press "OK" to add it, the listview's elements gets duplicated all the time. I cant see why? Anyone who knows this problem?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

The problem seems to be in my listAdapter =/ when I scroll up or down the text get duplicated for some reason, here's my code:

```
 class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Friend>{

    private ImageView img;
    private TextView name, number;
    private Context context;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Friend> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        LayoutInflater vi;

        if(v == null){
            vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }

        Friend item = getItem(position);

        name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        number = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.number);

        name.append(item.getName());
        number.append(item.getNumber());

        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean to call name.append and number.append? I think name.setText and number.setText sounds more appropriate. The append methods will keep adding more and more text.